# WPF CustomControl hides Children

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

My CustomControl changes the Visibility of it's children when i assign a value to a child. Here's my code

```
<UserControl x:Class="CrossProjectUserControls.controls.OnOffSwitch"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CrossProjectUserControls.controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Background="White" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imgSwitch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxHeight="30" MinWidth="80" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="imgSwitch_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Source="/CrossProjectUserControls;component/res/icons/onoffswitch/switch_off_1_V3_100x40.png" Margin="3,3,0,3"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblText" Content="{Binding Text}" Margin="83,3,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" Background="#FF633C3C"/>

</Grid>
```

```
public partial class OnOffSwitch : UserControl {

    private BitmapImage bmpOn = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/MentorPlus;component/res/icons/onoffswitch/switch_off_1_V3_100x40.png", UriKind.Relative));
    private BitmapImage bmpOff = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/MentorPlus;component/res/icons/onoffswitch/switch_on_1_V3_100x40.png", UriKind.Relative));

    private bool isOn = false;
    private string text = "Debug";

    public bool IsOn
    {
        get { return isOn; }
        set
        {
            isOn = value;
            ReloadUI();
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; lblText.Content = text; }
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent SwitchEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Switched", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(OnOffSwitch));

    public OnOffSwitch() {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void InitializeControls() {
        //this.lblText.Content = text;

        //this.imgSwitch.Source = bmpOff;
    }

    public void Switch() {
        IsOn = !IsOn;
    }

    private void ReloadUI() {
        if (this.IsOn == true) {
            this.imgSwitch.Source = bmpOn;
        } else if (this.IsOn == false) {
            this.imgSwitch.Source = bmpOff;
        }
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler Switched
    {
        add { AddHandler(SwitchEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SwitchEvent, value); }
    }

    void RaiseSwitchEvent() {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(OnOffSwitch.SwitchEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    #region Events
    private void imgSwitch_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        Switch();
        RaiseSwitchEvent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        InitializeControls();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

So the Label is totally hidden if i assign a string to it's content like **this.lblText.Content = "Test"**. Is there something I am missing or did I do something wrong?

Thanks for every help

Comment: Do you actually see nothing on  your control or just label with background without image on top?

Comment: I don't see where your DataContext is assigned. Maybe this is the reason that your binding is not working.

Comment: Solved it.. Sorry Guys, i had set Width and Height of the complete Control on my UI. Sometimes the weirdest errors come from the simplest lines of code -.-'

Thank you all for your help!